# What are the diffences between evntwin and evntcmd?

Tags: windows, snmp, windows-event-log

I want to send my eventlog via SNMP trap in order to monitor it,
but something is not clear in my mind.

I saw i need to configure traps destination in SNMP service in services.msc and 
then I also need to add some eventlogs to send via SNMP in the evntwin tool.
I some documentation I saw that I need to export my eventlog list with evntwin (export) tool to then use envtcmd to configure trap destinations.

So why i need evntcmd as I already configured trap destinations in service SNMP configure panel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this technet documentation : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684482.aspx#_Using_ETT_to_Translate_Events_to_Tr

evntwin is used to configure the EventLog to Trap translation. It produces a config file that can then be deployed on other computers using evntcmd.

Now get back to work !